# Issues Getting Intel XDK to run - hangs on startup

Tags: startup, intel-xdk

I've checked googles and stacks and cannot find an answer for my issue, so I'm asking here.

I've installed Intel XDK 2 on my system (Win 7 64b Pro) but cannot get it to start up. I've uninstalled and reinstalled.

I have it installed in the default directory \users\\AppData\Intel\XDK (I think that was it) so there shouldn't be an issue with permissions.

It comes up with the "Initializing page" but nothing else. I've left it be for about 1 hour while I worked on something else, but the window never changes and the app doesn't start.  If I kill it and reopen it says that it didn't close properly and asks if I want a normal or safe start; I've tried both options.

Anyone have any issue with this?

(and please don't suggest phonegap / cordova... I've tried to install that on Eclipse and Visual Studio and both have failed miserably to simply work, even with the googles assisting me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try:

-- Make sure you have a valid hosts file, for some folks this has been a problem getting the XDK to start, for unknown reasons, some systems either are missing their hosts file or have invalid entries which can sometimes cause trouble. On Windows, your hosts file is located here:

`\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

-- Uninstall the XDK and then completely remove these two directories from your system:

`%AppData%\..\Local\XDK`

`%AppData%\..\Local\Intel\XDK`

Comment: I tried that and restarted. Didn't seem to work. However, when I came back and restarted later it did. The only additional variable was time. So i'm guessing that I may have restarted too quickly after deleting Local? Not that it makes sense, but as I've said, time was the only variable that changed.

Comment: In my case, I killed the processes "nw.exe", "adb.exe" and "node.exe" (that was running bracket), and it started again as normal.

Comment: I killed  "nw.exe" , "adb.exe"  ( I think, intel XDK has its own adb  ) and "node.exe"  and than run  Intel-XDK. works fine..

Comment: Yes, the Intel XDK includes a copy of adb as part of it's distribution. It will, however, attempt to "play nice" with existing copies of the adb daemon that may already be running in the background of your system. Unfortunately, some recently released versions of adb are not compatible with the current release of the XDK (hoping to see that fixed in a future release of the XDK). So it is possible to get a conflict; in that case it is best to kill all instances of adb before starting the XDK.